# O365 users mailbox usage size through GraphAPI

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I'm tying to used below **Graph api call** .This api call  saying, period 'specifies the length of time over which the report is aggregated. The supported values for **{period_value}** are: D7, D30, D90, and D180. These values follow the format Dn where n represents the number of days over which the report is aggregated.' I didn't get why aggregating rather than give mailboxsize or used storage until the reporting day. Is there any possible way to **get storage size** of each user?

GET [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getMailboxUsageDetail(period='D7')](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getMailboxUsageDetail(period=%27D7%27))

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Currently you can only get aggregated report by specifying the length of time over which the report is to be aggregated.

Being said that, please file a [user voice](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform) for your specific ask so that it could be considered for future implementations.